# dwoo addPlugin not working

Tags: dwoo

I followed the tutorial on github how to implemented a Plugin as user-defined function.
I used exactly the same code as in the example: 

`$dwoo->addPlugin('email_safe', 'fix_address');`

But I get this error:
`Error: Class 'fix_address', does not exist`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function

```
function fix_address(Dwoo\Core $core, $str) {
     return $value;
}
```

it works when using a class, which is odd because it says functions are allowed too

```
class fix_address{
    public static function process($value) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```